# count the number of people who like me, number of people I like, and the intersection

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-14

- i have two tables `users` and `votes`
- suppose I have a row in the `votes` table where

```
uid = alice
b_uid = bob
liked = 1
```

- this means alice likes bob
- I want to count the stats for a user Charlie, i.e.

  - how many people does Charlie like?
  - How many people like Charlie?
  - how many pairs are there? (x likes Charlie, and Charlie likes x)
- my attempt is as follows

```python
def get_user_stat(uid):
    sql1 = f"""
    select *,
        (
            select count(uid)
            from votes
            where b_uid = u.uid and liked = 1
        ) as cnt_liked_me,
        (
            select count(uid)
            from votes
            where uid = u.uid and liked = 1
        ) as cnt_i_liked,
        (
            select count(uid)
            from votes
            where uid in (
                select b_uid
                from votes
                where uid = u.uid and liked = 1
            ) and b_uid = u.uid and liked = 1
        ) as cnt_both_liked
    from users u
    where uid = '{uid}'
    limit 1
    """
    return sql1
```

- the above code seems to work, but as you can see there is a redundancy to find `cnt_both_liked`, **how can I better approach this problem?**

Comment: Which database system and version?

Comment: @J.D.  PostgreSQL 14.4

Answer (score 1):

I'm apologize, my solution was all wrong.
Here is a solution that works correctly:

```
SELECT 'Liked' AS stat, SUM(liked) AS liked 
  FROM votes 
  WHERE uid = Charlie AND liked = 1

UNION ALL   

SELECT 'Likes' AS stat, SUM(liked) AS liked 
  FROM votes 
  WHERE b_uid = Charlie AND liked = 1

UNION ALL   

SELECT 'Mutuals' AS stat, SUM(w.liked) AS liked 
  FROM votes AS w
  JOIN votes AS z ON w.b_uid = z.uid
                 AND z.b_uid = w.uid
  WHERE w.uid = Charlie AND w.liked = 1 AND z.liked = 1
;
```